# I want to write a route/endpoint in express to handle ajax post requests and use that route/endpoint to update a json file's data

Tags: javascript, json, express

I'm creating a server that pulls JSON data from a dir and parses it into a file that can be read in the front end through $.getJSON(). My question is how do I update the data in the front end file and see it update in the file itself?

I tried using ajax's post method but I'm getting a 404 error. I've found that I need to write an "end-point" to point the ajax URL to. Where do I put this Javascript endpoint file/how do I write it in the express.

Server Code:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var curl = require('curl');
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.listen(3030, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3030!')
})
// Document

var dirBuf = Buffer.from('public/assets/jsonfiles')
fs.readdir(dirBuf, (err, files) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
    }
    else {
        var all = [];
        //files
        files.forEach(function(filename) {
            var txt = fs.readFileSync('public/assets/jsonfiles/' + filename);
            var filecontents = JSON.parse(txt)
            all = (all.concat(filecontents));
        })
        var back = JSON.stringify(all, null, 2)
        /* UNCOMMENT TO CREATE FRONT END FILE */
        //  fs.writeFileSync('public/assets/frontEndJSON/allrequests.json', back)
    }
});
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    fs.writeFileSync('public/assets/frontEndJSON/allrequests.json', req.body)
})
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index')
});
```

Front-end Javascript code(ajax requests):

```
var back = JSON.stringify(q.items, null, 2)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'public/assets/js/controller.js',
        data: back,
        dataType: 'json'
    })
}
```

my file structure looks like this:

```
-project-folder
 -public
  -assets
    -FronendFiles
     -json file I read from and want to update
    -js
      -main.js
 -server.js
```

Comment: That's what `app.post(url, ...)` does.

Comment: @SLaks I know that's the express method I'm suppose to be using but what url do I use, and what do I put in the ajax url:

Comment: You can pick any URL you want.